# UI - How to display GridView and Linear layout togather

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to display GridView (with text and image) and group of text box below grid view.

Problem is my gridview do not have fixed entries. It is varying between 1 & 10. I want to resize it as per count of items in grid view. How can i do that? Where can i get height of gridview in JAVA code?

Also, i want to display my group of text boxes ALWAYS at bottom of activity. How can i do that?

Thanks,
JC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to resize it as per count of items in grid view.

I really don't recommend that.

> Also, i want to display my group of text boxes ALWAYS at bottom of activity. How can i do that?

Step #1: Put the `GridView` and the `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`

Step #2: Anchor the `LinearLayout` to the bottom via `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Step #3: Anchor the `GridView` to the top (`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`) and to the top of the `LinearLayout` (`android:layout_above="..."`)

This will cause your `GridView` to expand to fill the space in the `RelativeLayout` except that which is taken up by the `LinearLayout` at the bottom. You can size and position the `RelativeLayout` yourself as you see fit (e.g., set width and height to `fill_parent` to have it fill the screen).

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked like a champ !! this will allow gridview to span till remaining space. What will happen if entries in grid view are more, will it scroll or overlay?  It is scrolling so it will work for me...again thanks !!

Comment: @JRC: "What will happen if entries in grid view are more, will it scroll or overlay?" -- scroll. It will not overlap the `LinearLayout`.